# Суть задачи заключается в слове плавной появления?

Tags: jquery

У меня есть блок, они сверстаны уже по сетке. Я сделал так, чтобы они менялись random свои места (по секте) со временем. Теперь я хочу привязать плавное появление блоков это .fadeIn (800) или transition.
А вот как реализовать дальше незнаю))
Суть задачи заключается в слове плавной появления.

```js
$(function myFunc() {
  var parent = $("#shuffle");
  var divs = parent.children();
  while (divs.length) {
    parent.append(divs.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length), 1)[0]);
  }

  setTimeout(myFunc, 2000);

});
```

```css
#shuffle div {
  float: left;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  color: #fcfcfc;
  background-color: #777;
  margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="shuffle">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: javascript (jquery)
понадобилось какое-то время, чтобы понять как это работает :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function myFunc() {
  var parent = $("#shuffle");
  var divs = parent.children();
  divs.css({
    "opacity": 0.1
  })
  let arr = [];
  while (divs.length) {
    parent.append(divs.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length), 1)[0]);
  }
  $("#shuffle div").animate({
    opacity: 1
  }, 1500)
  setTimeout(myFunc, 2000);

});
```

```css
#shuffle div {
  float: left;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  color: #fcfcfc;
  background-color: #777;
  margin: 3px;
  opacity: 0.1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="shuffle">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно поняла вопрос, то:

Для плавного появления каждый раз рандомных блоков, то так

```js
$(function myFunc() {
  var parent = $("#shuffle");
  var divs = parent.children();
  parent.fadeIn(800);
  while (divs.length) {
    parent.append(divs.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length), 1)[0]);
  }
  parent.fadeOut(800);
  setTimeout(myFunc, 2000);
});
```

```html
<div id="shuffle" style="display: none">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Если для появления 1 раза - уберите `parent.fadeOut(800);`

Надеюсь помогла